# Filtering and creating a new CSV file from data matching a specific string in a column

Tags: python, csv, match, row

I have a csv file file and want to filter it and create a new file from it. In the csv file there is a column "path". I want to filter the data which has "A/B/C" in the column "path". and write wntire row of those columns to a new csv file. Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this?

```py
def read_csv():
    df=pd.read_csv("demo_file.csv",usecols=["Path"])
    for row in df:
        if "A/B/C" in row:
```

I am not sure how can i write the whole rows into a new csv file.

Answer (score 0):

i can not really test it unless you provide the CSV. but you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("demo_file.csv")

# Filter rows where 'Path' column contains "A/B/C"
filtered_df = df[df['Path'].str.contains("A/B/C")]

# Write the filtered dataframe to a new CSV file
filtered_df.to_csv("filtered_file.csv", index=False)
```